# Is there an analytic solution to this system of equations? If so, how can I obtain it? Mathematica is running forever

Tags: equation-solving

I am wondering whether there is an analytic (closed-form) solution for $a_S$ for the system of equations below. $\alpha_N$, $Y_S$, and $\epsilon$ are fixed (exogenous) parameters, and I am interested in how the solution for $a_S$ depends on them.

I tried to solve the system of equations using "Solve". However, Mathematica is running forever, which makes me wonder if there is an analytic solution, and if so, what I might need to do to obtain it (e.g., simplify first).

I tried to obtain closed-form solutions if I fix parameter values. I realized that this is possible if I fix the value of $\epsilon$ (e.g., setting $\epsilon = 1$). However, I would like to obtain a closed form solution of $a_S$ as a function of $\epsilon$. The parameter values could be restricted to $\alpha_N \in (0,1)$ and $\epsilon \in (0,1]$ (I tried whether solutions can be found under these assumptions but without success).

[image: Screenshot of system of equations]

Here's the Mathematica code in InputForm:

```
solsimple = Solve[Subscript[\[Alpha], N]/Subscript[x, N] == Subscript[\[Lambda], N] && (1 - Subscript[\[Alpha], N])/Subscript[x, S] == Subscript[\[Lambda], S] && 
((Subscript[\[Lambda], N]*(2*Subscript[a, S]))/Subscript[Y, S] - (Subscript[\[Lambda], N]*(2*Subscript[Y, S])^\[Epsilon])/(3*Subscript[a, S])^2 - (Subscript[\[Lambda], S]*Subscript[Y, S]^\[Epsilon])/(3*Subscript[a, S])^2)/
  ((Subscript[\[Lambda], S]*2*Subscript[a, S])/Subscript[Y, S] - (Subscript[\[Lambda], N]*(2*Subscript[Y, S])^\[Epsilon])/(3*Subscript[a, S])^2 - (Subscript[\[Lambda], S]*Subscript[Y, S]^\[Epsilon])/(3*Subscript[a, S])^2) == -2^(-1) && 
Subscript[x, N] == 2*Subscript[Y, S] - (2*Subscript[a, S])^2/(2*Subscript[Y, S]) - (2*Subscript[Y, S])^\[Epsilon]/(3*Subscript[a, S]) && 
Subscript[x, S] == Subscript[Y, S] - Subscript[a, S]^2/Subscript[Y, S] - Subscript[Y, S]^\[Epsilon]/(3*Subscript[a, S]), {Subscript[\[Lambda], N], Subscript[\[Lambda], S], Subscript[x, N], Subscript[x, S], Subscript[a, S]}, Reals]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: In general, finding an analytic (closed-form) solution for any particular system of equations has probability zero. You could be lucky but probably not. You may want to try to find a power series solution instead.

Comment: `N` has a pre-defined meaning and should never be used in any user-defined sense.

Comment: I am going to do questionable things here that you must justify afterwards. I eliminated all denominators. I forced `YS^epsilon` into `YS^(1+epsilon)` and  eliminated all those, eliminating one equation. All `epsilon` were then `2^epsilon` and I replaced those with `ep2` I Simplify and I get to `Reduce[ {aN==lN*xN,aN==1-lS*xS,6*aS^3*(2*lN+lS)==(ep2*lN+lS)*-(3*aS^3+3*aS*(xS-YS)*YS), 6*aS^3+3*aS*(xN-2*YS)*YS+ep2*-(3*aS^3+3*aS*(xS-YS)*YS)==0},{lN,lS,xN,xS,aS}] //Simplify` and it returns a solution in a few seconds. Study what I did. Was everything I did legal and can you use that solution?

Comment: `Solve` will also solve that system and return a solution in a different form.

Comment: Thank you all for your help - I really appreciate it!
@Somos: Well I can find analytical solutions once I specify the parameter $\epsilon$, but not as a function of $\epsilon$. I'm not sure yet why that is. Any idea? Also, I don't know how to find power series solutions. Do you think this is promising for this system of equations? If so, I'll look into it.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks so much for your effort of trying to solve it - this is very helpful! I think everything you did was legal. I verified it for certain parameter values by comparing it to numerical results (I'm also solving the same system of equations numerically).

Did you make these modifications to make it easier/quicker for Mathematica to solve?

However, I can't quite use it yet. The problem with the `Reduce` command is that it writes the solution for `aS` as a function of other variables (`xN` and `xS`) and I'd like a solution in terms of only parameters.

Comment: @Bill: And the issue with the `Solve` command is that it doesn't solve for `aS` for 2 of the 5 solutions (and these are the ones I'm interested in). Mathematica shows the message "Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.". I think this is because we now have 5 variables but only 4 equations.

Any further ideas of how I could get a solution for `aS` in terms of only parameter values?

Comment: I also noticed that I had a typo in my question (apologies!). I'm trying to obtain a closed-form solution for $a_S$, not $a_N$. I corrected this in the question. Moreover, I noticed that the parameter choice $\alpha$ might not have been wise, since it might be confused with the variable $a$.

Comment: I made the changes to make it fast. I can't quite see your monitor from here so I can't tell exactly which results are in the wrong form and which "2 of the 5 solutions" you are talking about. If you can edit your original post, use `Reduce`, show the all the result and then show exactly which equations involving `aS` need to be turned in exactly what form then I can try and see what I can do. But with your equations I'm not sure it is possible to end up with everything as a function of nothing but `aN,aS,YS,epsilon` Can you try using `Eliminate` to remove n particular vars from n+1 equations?